# Cómo desactivar este warning: "Warning: Undefined array key "type" in [...] online 469

Tags: php, array, undefined

tengo un problema con un warning que aparece cuando trato de cambiar de idioma mi web, suele suceder cuando cambio 2 veces el idioma. También sucede cuando trato de crear una propiedad como visitante. He contactado con WPML (plugin que uso de multilenguaje) pero no me dan soluciones porque dicen que no tiene que ver con ellos, he contactado con elementor pero no me responden.

Os adjunto el mensaje que aparece:
Warning: Undefined array key "type" in /homepages/37/d579385722/htdocs/clickandbuilds/AntaalLife/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/base/controls-stack.php on line 469

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Os adjunto una captura del código en la línea 469. Perdonad la ignorancia, soy novato. Sólo trato de ayudar a mi familia con un negocio.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias de antemano!

Comment: Vete a la línea 469 de este archivo `/homepages/37/d579385722/htdocs/clickandbuilds/AntaalLife/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/base/controls-stack.php` y péganos el código en la pregunta si quieres que te ayudemos. Puedes modificar la pregunta pulsando sobre el enlace [edit] que aparece en el pie de la misma.

Comment: y por lo que parece no eres el único que le pasa: https://trovend.com/industry-expertise/.  Eso tiene pinta de ser cosa de los de elementor y ellos tendria que resolverlo, pues cualquier cambio que hagas en ese archivo luego lo podrian revertir en una actualización y volverias a estar igual si no lo han arreglado en la misma.

Comment: La solución no es *desactivar* el Warning, sino **corregir** el código que lo produce. *Es que es un plugin*. Pues no deberías depender de demasiados plugin en WP, así como son incapaces de corregir esto, el plugin podría tener un grave agujero de seguridad que tampoco corregirán y tu sitio puede verse comprometido. Salvo contadas excepciones, es mejor que programes tu propio código y para cosas complejas, puedes valerte de librerías que ya existen. Ganarás en seguridad y en rapidez, haciendo que cada vez más tu sitio dependa de plugins de WP.

Comment: Acabo de añadir una captura de la línea del archivo control-stacks.php
Entiendo lo que me comentáis de que programe mi propio código, pero eso la web la estoy intentando hacer para ayudar a la familia con un negocio, ni lo cobro ni nada. Sólo me gustaría poder corregir el warning y próximamente ya ver si es útil o no la web. Muchas gracias por vuestros comentarios. Ojalá se pueda corregir.

Comment: puedes ir a php.ini y corregir para que no te muestre los Warning, o intentar con un `error_reporting(E_ERROR);` al inicio del codigo https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: El comentario de John ha sido el que me ha ayudado. Por si alguien tiene el mismo problema.